# TFS wok items Migration issue to DevOps

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools, vsts-sync-migrator

Hi Facing project not found issue when project name is deifferent from TFS. I have project in TFS project collection and i want to migrtae data using migration tool to Devops.

TFS Link https://Server/tfs/DefaultCollection/StudentData

DevOps https://dev.azure.com/DevOps/**Studentmanagement**

having projects name differently as specified above is failing not able to migrate data.Query bit used below

"QueryBit": "AND ([System.IterationPath]='StudentData\Release 4.7.0' OR [System.IterationPath]='StudentData\Release 4.7.1') AND [System.State]<>'Removed'",

#azure-devops-migration-tools

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to use the source or target Project name in the QueryBit.